# Grouping / limiting results using multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to display data from three tables, only showing limited linked data.

Table examples -
Customers: CustomerName, CustomerID
Accounts: AccountName, AccountID, CustomerID
Transactions: TransactionAmount, TransactionDate, TransactionID, AccountID, CustomerID

Customers may not have any linked Accounts, but could have multiple.
Accounts may not have any linked Transactions, but could have multiple.

There are two required ways of displaying the data:

1. Top 200 Transactions by TransactionDate, **but** only one per Account (most recent TransactionDate). Display CustomerName, AccountName, TransactionAmount.
2. Result of search Customername, or AccountName, or TransactionID.
   a. If searched by CustomerName, display CustomerName, AccountName with highest AccountID only, plus related TransactionAmount using only the most recent TransactionDate. There may not be any Accounts or Transactions for the Customer.
   b. If searched by AccountName, display CustomerName, AccountName, and related TransactionAmount using only the most recent TransactionDate. There may not be any Transactions for the Customer.
   c. If searched by TransactionID, display CustomerName, AccountName, and TransactionAmount. (This one is straightforward)

I am having trouble figuring out how to do the groupings and other aggregate functions required to limit the data as needed.
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What SQL have you created so far, and what results did you get?

Answer (score 0):

1) to limit transactions to the latest ones, you can do something like

```
with LatestTransactionByAccount as (
  select * from Transactions t
  where not exists (
    select 1 from Transactions t2 where t2.AccountID = t.AccountID
    and t2.TransactionDate < t.TransactionDate)
)
select ...
from LatestTransactionByAccount
join ...
```

2) works similarly